# Select user by meta value - Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I have this code:

```
    $user = get_users( array (
            'meta_query' => array(
                array(
                    'meta_key'     => 'token',
                    'meta_value'   => '344793879185b4924a7d',
                ),
                'orderby'      => 'meta_value',
                'order'        => 'DESC',
                'number'       => '10',
            )
        ) );

        return count($user);
```

This returns me all the users.

This returns `false`, with notice:

> Only variables should be passed by reference in

```
$user = reset(
   get_users(
   array(
   'meta_key' => 'token',
   'meta_value' => '344793879185b4924a7d',
   'number' => 1,
   'count_total' => false
  )
)
);
```

There is only one user with that metakey with that value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The warning

> Only variables should be passed by reference in

is because you are passing the function result directly into reset function which expects a variable.

Apart from that the result that you are getting when using the second code will output a `wp_user` object and not an array so resetting the indexing is not actually needed.

Your code should be something like this:

```
$user = get_users(
    array(
        'meta_key' => 'token',
        'meta_value' => '344793879185b4924a7d',
        'number' => 1,
        'count_total' => false
    )
);
```

Comment: Yes, but this doesn't matter, because it returns empty array, but there is a user with that token.

Comment: Did you tried using just the `meta_key`, `meta_value` and `meta_compare` parameters without using `number` and `count_total`?

Comment: It returns the right user, but the problem is that it returns it always, even, if that token  value is not equal . There is only one user, not only with that token value, but with that meta key, too. I remember there is something about selecting for items which that token, even not exists.

Comment: Ok, we have a winner. The last one works without count/total, thanks.

Comment: Yeah!! That's great.